# dplyr::if_else() doesn't run a function correctly as an outcome, whereas base ifelse() does perfectly. Why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I understand the primary difference between `dplyr::if_else()` and base `ifelse()`: strict type-checking between true and false outcomes in the former.

However I have noticed another difference, and I'm wondering if it's the intended behaviour or if I am just doing it wrong.

Here's some simple code:

```
library(dplyr)

choose_number <- function() {
  n <- readline("Choose a number between 1 and 4: ")
  n <- as.integer(n)
  if (between(n, 1, 4)) { return(n) }
  else { return(NA_integer_) }
}

# base ifelse() - works perfectly
get_answer <- function(pick = FALSE, n = 2) {
  n <- ifelse(pick, choose_number(), as.integer(n))
  return(n)
}

# dplyr::if_else() - does not work in the same way
get_answer <- function(pick = FALSE, n = 2) {
  n <- if_else(pick, choose_number(), as.integer(n))
  return(n)
}
```

I want `get_answer()` to call `choose_number()` only when the `pick` argument is TRUE. Otherwise it should just return the value of `n`. It does this perfectly with base `ifelse()` in the code above, but not with the `dplyr` version.

**The `dplyr` version does not return an error or warning, however**; it still calls `choose_number()` but ignores the result and just returns the default value of `n`.

The `true` option for `if_else`, `choose_number()`, will return an integer, as will the `false` option. So in my mind the type-checking feature of `if_else` should be satisfied.

Comment: You're using `if_else` on an always-single vector? That's just unnecessary, why not use `if`?

Comment: Regardless of your rationale for choosing against the simpler `if`, you cannot rely on a vectorized `ifelse` or `dplyr::if_else` or `data.table::fifelse` to short-circuit your logic; it's generally safer to assume that all of both vectors will be calculated regardless of your possibly-extrinsic condition. (The fact that base `ifelse` is doing it does not mean that `if_else` is wrong, imo.)

Comment: You need `get_answer <- function(pick = FALSE, n = 2L) {`

Comment: @r2evans because stupid and tired! thank you - I think I just got caught up in using dplyr (obv the code I'm working with is more complex - this here was just an abstracted example). I take your point about extrinsic-ness of the condition satisfaction. I can easily re-write using if and else. I suppose I was just interested in why it didn't work with the dplyr version anyway. I'll leave the question up unless you recommend deleting.

Comment: @asfa no because I call `as.integer` in the function, and I may wish to pass a different bare numeric argument to `get_answer()` not just the default.

Comment: There are some things that base `ifelse` does *wrong* (or poorly or inconsistently). Some of them are (imo) the impetus for `dplyr::if_else`. (As two examples, try `ifelse(T,Sys.time(),Sys.time())` and `ifelse(T,1,"A")`. The first strips attributes, the second is inconsistent from a data perspective.)

Comment: I think the main question is why `dplyr::if_else` calls `choose_number()` at the first place when `pick` is `FALSE` .

Comment: @RonakShah yes i was perplexed by that

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because `dplyr::if_else()` is more strict than `ifelse()`.

`dplyr::if_else()` needs to check that both `true` and `false` are the same type and class before it is able to execute. since `choose_number()` is a function, it needs to be resolved first for this class check to take place, so it runs even when your `condition` is FALSE.

more info here:
https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/if_else.html